# How can two values be equal, but also not equal?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When I run the following queries:

```
DECLARE 
    @val VARCHAR(10) = 'not null'
    , @val2 VARCHAR(10) = NULL

-- Test 1.
IF @val <> @val2 SELECT 'Test 1. They are not equal' -- Are they equal?
ELSE SELECT 'Test 1. They are equal'

-- Test 2.
IF @val = @val2 SELECT 'Test 2. They are equal' -- Are they not equal
ELSE SELECT 'Test 2. They are not equal'
```

I get the following output:

```
Test 1. They are equal
Test 2. They are not equal
```

Please can someone explain these results?

Comment: A null `=` or `<>` comparison is never TRUE. I.e. you will get the `else` value in both cases.

Comment: val VARCHAR(10) = 'not null' is a string and val2 VARCHAR(10) = NULL is the garbage value stored in val2

Comment: Any comparison with `NULL` is always false, therefore in both comparisons the `ELSE` branch is took.

Comment: @Alejandro, not false, unknown.

Comment: @jarlh Sure, it's also `NULL`, but in a boolean context (like those `IF`s), they're always interpreted as false (there is no third value in an `IF`/`ELSE` construct).

Comment: @Alejandro but `NOT (NULL = NULL)` is not true either, so "false" is technically not correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any comparison against NULL will never be true.

So that code can only return the `ELSE` values.

There's often a common misunderstanding about the meaning of NULL in SQL.

At first glance one assumes that NULL means "empty".
And then it would strike as odd that empty doesn't equal empty, and also isn't different from empty.

But it's easier to understand when NULL is understood as "unknown".
Because two unknowns don't have to be the same.
And one can't say that two unknowns are different either.
Even a "known" could be different from an "unknown", but it also could be the same.
Logic just doesn't know...  Hence `NULL`.

But seeing is believing, so let's show this through some examples.
Here's a simple SQL snippet, to showcase how comparisons treat them NULL's.

```
-- Sample data
DECLARE @Table TABLE
(
  Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  Col1 VARCHAR(42),
  Col2 VARCHAR(42)
);

INSERT INTO @Table 
(Col1, Col2) VALUES
('something', NULL),
(NULL, '>4&×'),
(NULL, NULL),
('same', 'same'),
('same is not', 'different is');

SELECT t.*
, CAST(IIF(col1 = col2, 1, 0) AS BIT) AS IsEqual
, CAST(IIF(col1 <> col2, 1, 0) AS BIT) AS IsNotEqual
, CAST(IIF(col1 = col2 OR (col1 IS NULL AND col2 IS NULL), 1, 0) AS BIT) AS IsNotDistinctFrom
, CAST(IIF(col1 != col2 OR (col1 IS NOT NULL AND col2 IS NULL) OR (col1 IS NULL AND col2 IS NOT NULL), 1, 0) AS BIT) AS IsDistinctFrom
, CAST(IIF(col1 > col2, 1, 0) AS BIT) AS IsGreaterThen
FROM @Table t
ORDER BY Id;
```

**Returns:**

> ```
> Id | Col1        | Col2         | IsEqual | IsNotEqual | IsNotDistinctFrom | IsDistinctFrom | IsGreaterThen
> -: | :---------- | :----------- | :------ | :--------- | :---------------- | :------------- | :------------
>  1 | something   | null         | False   | False      | False             | True           | False        
>  2 | null        | >4&×        | False   | False      | False             | True           | False        
>  3 | null        | null         | False   | False      | True              | False          | False        
>  4 | same        | same         | True    | False      | True              | False          | False        
>  5 | same is not | different is | False   | True       | False             | True           | True
> ```

Jup, NULL will be NULL.

A test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e7baf1d234c00add7398c035e33a614c)*

About the `IsNotDistinctFrom` & `IsDistinctFrom` columns?
I merely included them since there exists also a `NULL-aware` comparison in Standard SQL.
More details about that [here](https://modern-sql.com/feature/is-distinct-from)

Comment: Thank you so much for your brilliant explanation. I completely forgot about IS NOT NULL and IS NULL.

Comment: Thanks for the support :)  Well, it's quite simple really, once you get it.  And if one wants to compare against empty strings then one could make the varchar non-nullable, and insert empty strings.

Answer (score 6):

This is because of three valued logic in SQL. Any comparison with `NULL` value evalutes to `unknown`, which can be thought of as not true (quite obvious, when stated like that).

Refer to this [article.](https://modern-sql.com/concept/three-valued-logic)

Comment: You forget option "set ansi_nulls". If run "set ansi_nulls off" then result will be next: the same, the same. Of course, if we are talking about SQL Server.

Comment: While true about unknown, i heavily argue against calling it false. Since in three valued logic unknown is very much different to false. As argumented by your link as well. (Chapter 6 in the link)

Comment: I would say "`unknown`, which can be thought of as not true".

Comment: @DKramer While you're right, I just mentioned way of interpreting. Article is for clearng that out :)

Comment: @DanGuzman Acutally I was thinking about it :) corrected, thanks.

Comment: @Максим Золотенко That option is deprecated and setting it to OFF in future versions will result in an error. Read here: [SET ANSI_NULLS (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql).

Comment: @TT Yes. But it is still valid.

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine. 
In the first `if @val=@val2` then you should print `the same` instead of `not the same`.
You should add `begin` and `end` blocks after `if` condition declared.
Just check it out below script working fine.

```
    DECLARE 
    @val VARCHAR(10) = 'not null'
    , @val2 VARCHAR(10) = NULL

     IF @val = @val2 
     begin
       SELECT 'the same' -- Is it equal?
     end 
     ELSE 
      begin
         SELECT 'not the same'
     end 
     IF @val <> @val2 
     begin 
       SELECT 'the same' -- Is it not equal?
    end
    ELSE 
    begin 
       SELECT 'not the same'
    end
```

Comment: While this answer isn't quite correct, I really appreciate that you took the time to help me. Thank you very much. Luckily, LukStorms cracked the problem wide open. Please check out their answers for an excellent explanation of the solution.